# How to execute code fully before load xul file?

Tags: javascript, load, xul

I have a script that I add to my xul file, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Bindings -->
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://test/content/bindings.css" type="text/css"?>

<mywindow id="myWindowID" width="800" height="600"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://greenfox/content/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" />

</mywindow>
```

and on `mywindow` constructor (at the binding) I use a function of my scrip, called 'print'.

The problem is that sometimes, my script doesn't load really fast before it's used, and I get the message

> We are unable to Print or Print
>   Preview this page.

..which is related to the Printer usage.

**Please note that** I'm not trying to use the Printer, I'm trying to use my own `print` method (in the script that doesn't loaded in time) to simply write on the screen.

So, any idea how can I make the xul file wait till my script is completely loaded?

Comment: Seriously, if your script takes so long to load then you just cannot use your functions until it is loaded. You don't want to freeze the whole browser just to load your script, do you?

Comment: @Felix Kling actually, I'ts a desktop application, so there's no problem with the loading time.

Comment: Oops sorry then. For me XUL is so tightly connected to Firefox, I sometimes forget then you can use it independently ;) Nevermind!

Comment: @Felix Kling you may find interesting to know that I monitored my solution (below) and find out that I just needed 1 milis more for the script to load, so it's nothing either for a web app.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a variable "window.scriptsLoaded" and a loop on my class constructor that wait..

**-update**

also, it didn't work with `while(!window.scriptsLoaded)`, I needed to use:

```
function loadScripts() {
    if (!window.scriptsLoaded)
        setTimeout(loadScripts, 1)
    else
        loaded();
}
```

so the window.scriptsLoaded could be updated each time I check it. I don't really understand why.

**-update**

Actually, use "onload" showed itself a the better solution..